# How do you set up API for cancelling Paypal recurring payments?

Tags: php, paypal

I would like to give customers on my website the option to cancel a recurring Paypal subscription. I have code, but it is not working properly when the function is called.

```
function change_subscription_status($subID) {
    $api_request = 'USER=' . urlencode( 'api_user' )
                .  '&PWD=' . urlencode( 'api_pass' )
                .  '&SIGNATURE=' . urlencode( 'api_sig' )
                .  '&VERSION=124.0'
                .  '&METHOD=ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus'
                .  '&PROFILEID=' . urlencode( $subID )
                .  '&ACTION=' . urlencode( 'Cancel' )
                .  '&NOTE=' . urlencode( 'Profile cancelled at store' );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp' ); // For live transactions, change to 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp'
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1 );

    // Uncomment these to turn off server and peer verification
    // curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
    // curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );

    // Set the API parameters for this transaction
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $api_request );

    // Request response from PayPal
    $response = curl_exec( $ch );
}
```

Comment: You have to explain what "not working" means and any errors that you're getting.

Comment: @jonmrich By not working, it is not canceling the subscription, I am not receiving any errors.

Comment: What response do  you get back (`$response`)?

Comment: @jonmrich I did not even think about checking that, I'm so stupid.  I will try to tackle it based off the errors! Thanks!

Comment: If you need help, post the errors here and we'll give it a shot.

Comment: @jonmrich I got it! Thanks so much! I wasn't passing $subID through like I thought I was. After three hours of digging, your advice saved me in 10 minutes!

Comment: No problem. I spend most of my day digging through errors to figure out what I screwed up. It's always nice when the error actually tells you what to fix.